# Update Value Firebase Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble updating a value in my Firebase database with the key `status`. I just can't figure out how to access the child(id) in which it is an autoID. Should I have an attribute in my Swift 3 Entity? Or is there  a child(autoID) or something similar? I'm new in Firebase and Swift 3. Can any one help? This is my code:

```
 self.ref?.child("requests").queryOrdered(byChild: "Sender").queryEqual(toValue: self.items[indexPath.row].Sender).setValue("2", forKey: "status"))
```

[image: click here to see an image showing my database]

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 && Firebase 3

Hope this code will be help you...

```
    // create the reference you want to observe
    let myRequestRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("requests").queryOrdered(byChild: "Sender").queryEqual(toValue: self.items[indexPath.row].Sender)

    // check the sender value
    myRequestRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //get the sender key
        let senderKey = snapshot.key as String

        // create status ref for new status value
        let statusRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("requests").child(senderKey)

        // create new dict for status value
        let newValue = ["Status": 2] as [String: Any]

        statusRef.updateChildValues(newValue, withCompletionBlock: { (error, _) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to set status value")
            }
            print("Successfully set status value")
            // Update your UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Do anything with your UI
            }
        })
    }) { (error) in
        print("Failed to get snapshot", error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code inside `.observe`.  This will allow you to get the status and check that it's accessing the right child.   By using the child path below, it will override the `status` value but not the rest of the values inside the child.

```
self.ref?.child("requests").queryOrdered(byChild: "Sender").queryEqual(toValue: self.items[indexPath.row].Sender).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    if value != nil {
        print(value)
        print(value["status"])
        // If status is what you want, and prints out the correct status and 
        // correct child item

        // Update the status
        self.ref.child("requests/\(self.items[indexPath.row].Sender)/status").setValue("2")
    }
})
```

I haven't tested the code above, but you should be able to make minor tweaks to get it to work in your code and on your firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

You can update status value as below:

```
self.ref?.child("requests").queryOrdered(byChild: "Sender").queryEqual(toValue: self.items[indexPath.row].Sender).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
if value != nil {              
    self.ref.child("requests/(self.items[indexPath.row].Sender)").updateChildValues(["status":"2"])
}
})
```